# QWebSocket doesn't connect over TLS

Tags: qt, ssl, websocket, openssl

I have a WebSocket which works good over WebSocket protocol, but I can not switch to WebSocketSecure protocol, It doesn't generate any errors on server side, client says `error:141970DF:SSL routines:tls_construct_cke_psk_preamble:psk identity not found`. The certificate was generated by `certbot` and is used of for https web site on same domain.

Server code:

```cpp
    QSslConfiguration conf = server.sslConfiguration();
    QFile * privkey =
      new QFile{"/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"};

    privkey->open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    conf.setCaCertificates(QSslCertificate::fromPath(
      "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"));
    conf.setPrivateKey(QSslKey(privkey));
    conf.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_0);

    server.setSslConfiguration(conf);

    if (server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 54045)) {
        connect(
          &server, &QWebSocketServer::newConnection, this,
          &Server::onNewConnection);
        connect(&server, &QWebSocketServer::closed, this, &Server::closed);
        qDebug() << "server started";
    }
```

The client code:

```cpp
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtWebSockets 1.13

WebSocket {
    active: true
    url: "wss://example.com:54045"
}
```

Output of openSSL:

```sh
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:54045
CONNECTED(00000003)
140623606740288:error:14095126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:302:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 325 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Try using another TLS client like `openssl s_client` or even wget or curl to see the exchanges with the server. Also `setLocalCertificateChain` (based on its name, I now nothing about QT and "SSL") might need not just the certificate but the full chain of them up to root, concatenated one after another in the same file.

Comment: I switched to `setCaCertificates` and added the output of `openssl s_client`

Comment: You probably need SNI, so the `-servicename` switch to `openssl s_client` and and "eof while reading" is not a good sign, it may be a transport or firewall problem.